# Programmatically created square getting error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I am creating a square programmatically though when i run the app, nothing shows up.

```
var PB1: UIButton!

    func SetUpButton1() {

    var PB1: UIButton!
    PB1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "RS"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    PB1.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    PB1.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50)

    view.addSubview(PB1)

    }
```

Comment: Do you call the method SetUpButton1(); on app start? `UIButton(type:UIButtonType.Custom)`

Comment: 3 problems here: 1. I don't see your call to `UIButton` initializer. Did you called it somewhere before? 2. You "shadow" outer PB1 variable by local PB1. Remove `var PB1: UIButton!` line from `SetUpButton1` function. 3. Set `frame` instead of `bounds`.

Comment: Please debug your code before asking for external help! If the shown code actually *is* your code then you obviously *never* call `SetUpButton1` since the body of the method would simply crash your app. That can easily be verified via `print` statements or breakpoints inside the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to intialize PB1 object with UIButton()

```
  let PB1 = UIButton()
  PB1.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50)

  PB1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "RS"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  PB1.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)

  self.view.addSubview(PB1)
```

if you want to detect when is button pressed, you need to call addTarget(...) **which Associates a target object and action method with the control.**

```
PB1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and in your class create function named buttonPressed.

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: and you can also  use it by  let PB1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))

Comment: ,Thanks you very much. How would I detect when the button is pressed and do something when it is pressed?

Comment: @Noja Please ask one question at a time and show ***some*** effort achieving your goal on your own. It is a quite basic task to get a callback from a button!

Comment: i guess @luk2302 is right. you first need to verified the code using breakpoints.

Comment: @SahilBeri I am new to swift, and do not know much. Thank you for editing your answer, but how do you link the "button pressed" function to my button?

Comment: i recommend you to read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1

Comment: @Noja "I am new to swift, and do not know much" - then you have to get going reading tutorials, watching videos, playing around. We can and will not guide you step by step from scratch to an complete working application.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error while both of the lines 
please setup PB1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,50)
instead of PB1.bounds

Comment: he could use  button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50) ^^